# how to set a column to DATE format in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, format, xlsxwriter

I am working on a project where I am writing out onto an xlsx spreadsheet and need to format the one column for 'Date'.  I get the program to run and all but the column format is still set to 'General'.

Try this in a different way with different code to see if anyone answers.:

```
for row in cur.execute('''SELECT `Mapline`,`Plant`,`Date`,`Action` from AEReport'''):
    lengthOfHeadings = len(row)
    output = '%s-%s.xlsx' % ("AEReport",now.strftime("%m%d%Y-%H%M"))
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'strings_to_numbers':True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    format=workbook.add_format({'font_size':'8','border':True})
    format2=workbook.add_format({'font_size':'8','border':True,'num_format':'mm/dd/yy hh:mm'})
    count = 0
    for name in range(0,lengthOfHeadings):
        if name==row[2]:
            name=int(name)
            worksheet.write(counter, count, row[name],format2)
    else:
        worksheet.write(counter, count, row[name],format)
    count += 1
counter += 1
```

Slihthinden

Answer (score 9):

To get the date time format working, you would have to get the date value converted to a [excel serial date value](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm).

Here is an example showing how does it work:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'test_date':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=12, freq='M') })
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

data.test_date = data.test_date - pd.datetime(1899, 12, 31)

pd.core.format.header_style = None    
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['test']

formatdict = {'num_format':'mm/dd/yyyy'}
fmt = workbook.add_format(formatdict)

worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, fmt)

writer.save()
```

This is how the output will look like:
[image]

Comment: I would like to use this, but I keep getting an error when I try to run pandas atm.    ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']  I have done all the installing of pandas and the dependencies including numpy, so not sure what all is wrong.  Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] I have done all the installing of pandas and the dependencies including numpy, so not sure what all is wrong. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: If that is the error you are getting, say `import numpy as np` it shall rectify the error, even better show the piece of code that is failing, you may get a solution.

Comment: When I put in the import numpy statement I get another error - 'ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application'

Comment: Apparently the error above was due to my having updated my Python version yesterday and while I run on a 64-bit machine, I had been using a 32-bit Python and updated to the 64-bit version so it invalidated all of my modules that were 32-bit.  Trying this again

Comment: Converting the dates to integers is a great workaround since pandas overwrites all formatting when working with dates. I just had to make a small change to the column: `data['test_date'] = data['test_date'].dt.days`. Thanks!

Comment: Put it as a parameter in writer object may help, e.g. writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='mm-dd-yy') https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67995385/xlsxwriter-and-short-date-in-excel

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'})

worksheet.write(0, 0, datetime.today(),date_format)
```

result:
[image from Excel Generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDbQw.png)

Answer (score -1):

date = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd-mm-yyyy'})

worksheet.write(1, 1 , 02-12-199, date)